# Display prime numbers from a list in python. Error saying unsupported operands

Tags: python, list, primes

I am trying to create a program that gets an integer from the user and then creates a list of integers starting after 1 to the integer the user inputed. For example, if the user inputs "8", then a list will be created [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. After that I want it to go through each integer of the list and display only the prime numbers up to (or including) the user input.

```
def main():
    #get user input of integer
    user_integer = int(input('Please enter an integer greater than 1: '))
    #call function that creates list of numbers up to user input
    integer_list = create_list(user_integer)
    #call function that returns prime numbers
    prime_numbers = prime_number(integer_list)
    #display prime numbers
    print('The prime numbers up to the integer you entered are:', prime_numbers)

def create_list(x):
    integer_list = []
    numbers = 2
    while numbers != x:
        integer_list.append(numbers)
        numbers += 1
    return integer_list

def is_prime_number(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
             return False
        else:
             return True

def prime_number(x):
    prime_numbers = []
    for i in (x):
        if is_prime_number(i):
            prime_numbers.append(i)

    return (prime_numbers)

main()
```

Edit: I edited the code to include a function that tests each number individually if its a prime number. However, it seems to be returning only odd numbers rather than prime numbers. For example, if I enter "13" it returns a list of [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]. Obviously 9 is not a prime number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if x%i == 0:` — `x` is a list here, so `x%i` makes no sense. Whatever you're trying to do, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: `x` is a list. What are you intending `x%i` to do?

Comment: I want to iterate through the list to see if its a prime number. Would there be a better way of going about it?

Comment: To see if *what* is a prime number?  I'm not sure what "it" is supposed to be in that sentence; your antecedent is "the list", and a list cannot be a prime number.  There are quite a few algorithms for finding prime numbers; we're not sure which one you're trying to use, so we can't "fix" your code.  You might refer to any of the thousands of prime-number programs available on line.

Comment: You need to loop through all the numbers up to `sqrt(i)`, and test if `i % number == 0`.

Comment: You should split `prime_number` into two functions. Write another function `is_this_number_prime()` that takes a single number as a parameter, and returns whether it's prime. Then `prime_number()` can loop through `x` and call `is_this_number_prime(i)`.

Comment: I tried adding a function `is_prime_number(x)` that would return only a True or False statement and then having that be called in the `prime_number(x)` function. (what **Jtcruthers** recommended) However, it still won't test if each integer in the list is a prime number.

Comment: I added a function however, it is returning only odd numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to find the remainder of diving a list by a number. That is why you are getting the error: % is an unsupported operand for types list and int. I'd suggest breaking out the logic to determine if a number is prime, then in your for loop, call that method. If it returns true, add it to the prime numbers list.

```
def is_prime_number(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def prime_number(x):
    prime_numbers = []
    for i in (x):
        if is_prime_number(x):
            prime_numbers.append(i)
    return prime_numbers
```

You don't need parenthesis around lists, and since you aren't using the composite numbers list, you don't need to keep track of it. Pulling the logic into its own function helps make the code cleaner and easier to look at. Feel free to make optimizations to the prime number function as well

Comment: What is the 'n' in the line "if n%i ==0"? Also I am still getting the same problem as the 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: It was a typo, it meant to say num. I edited the code

Comment: Thank you! How would I include the list of prime numbers to also include the number entered if its a prime number? Right now if I enter "31" as the integer, it only displays up to prime number "29."

Comment: The method `is_prime_number` is what checks the number you give it. `for i in range(2,num)` is where it gets the range of numbers to check. Num is the number you passed into the function to check. Since it is going to num - 1 (which is what range does), just do `for i in range(2,num+1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be improved by eliminating the modulo calculation and looping.It is also better to use a tried and tested algorithm for generating primes called the  [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
def main():
    user_integer = int(input('Please enter an integer greater than 1: '))
    integer_list = list(range(2,user_integer))
    prime_numbers = prime_number(integer_list)

    #display prime numbers
    print('The prime numbers up to the integer you entered are:', prime_numbers)

def prime_number(nums):
    highest = nums[-1] + 1
    sieve = [True] * (highest)
    sieve[0:1] = [False, False]

    for i in range(2, highest):
        if sieve[i]:
            for j in range(2 * i,highest,i):
                sieve[j] = False
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, highest):
        if sieve[i]:
            primes.append(i)
    return primes


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```